# QML - dynamically create and destroy children of a TabBar

Tags: qt, qml

I have a problem when creating/destroying children of a TabBar dynamically.
This are the steps I'm making:

1. Click on "Add tabs" -> tabs are created correctly
2. Click on "Remove tabs" -> tabs are removed correctly
3. Click on "Add tabs" -> tabs are not created anymore

This is my main.qml code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 300
    height: 200
    visible: true

    TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        anchors.fill: parent
        function addTabButton(filename) {
            Qt.createQmlObject(
                'import QtQuick.Controls 2.15; TabButton { text: "' + filename + '" }',
                tabBar)
        }
    }

    Row {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        Button {
            text: "Add tabs"
            onClicked: { tabBar.addTabButton("Tab 1"); tabBar.addTabButton("Tab 2") }
        }

        Button {
            text: "Remove tabs"
            onClicked: {
                for (var i = 0; i < tabBar.children.length; i++) {
                    tabBar.children[i].destroy()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at [`Loader`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-loader.html)

Comment: I believe the reason is that the Tabs that you are adding are not direct children of the TabBar. Internally, the TabBar might place the tabs within a ListView, for instance. In that case, iterating through the TabBar's `children` property and destroying everything will actually be destroying the ListView (or whatever container they use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When thinking about dynamic creation and destruction of components, the first consideration should be whether can you use model/delegate, e.g. `ListModel`/`Repeater`. This can (1) reduce code complexity, (2) increase code stability, and (3) and easier to read and maintain.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    TabBar {
        width: parent.width
        Repeater {
            model: ListModel { id: listModel }
            TabButton { text: filename }
        }
    }
    footer: Frame {
        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width
            Button {
                text: "Add tabs"
                onClicked: {
                    listModel.append( { filename: "Tab 1" } );
                    listModel.append( { filename: "Tab 2" } );
                }
            }
            Button {
                text: "Remove Tabs"
                onClicked: listModel.clear()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACp3icnZHBbsIwDIbvfQqrJ7hU2o7htCHtxKRR7QUMMVu0NI5SdwyhvvsSSgsFgbT9hypOf+f3l5jKcxBYyrIx66/MjMpizk4C2/pyf4E7bqTO3vCDYJ9B1DuunjEci6St0fKpwGMgJ8WhGv6V5AmFzu1JFWuyChamlte0hD0YrcAOdTuyp8hGhF30Cf2Igo2x5LCiM2O36r4b5hiq4CUkzym75G1HdDHPPYSkPn20mdRNkz9pDYKrOr8ysJvbeJEU6a67kwbmAr0npyeRsaeLJ0d0eMihhensv+2PN9rHd9z+Cbikir8pPcx95tN4a0sYJtMbmf3jtb8Ff6+q)